# Mapbox GL JS : Unable to load external JSON file

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a simple function (onclick) that I am trying to create for my map. I am just trying to follow [This Mapbox tutorial on adding live data](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/) (json point) but I cannot get this to work with my map. For now, this is the only step I am trying to do.

I wrote a function that starts correctly after the click (verified with the alert popup) but the function does nothing else, as if it is empty. I am using Firefox which I know will display the data (chrome and edge do not). I have determined that I am somehow messing the code up when trying to put it into a function. Below is the code I started with for my function named *addMDA_toA*, and my map is named *topleftmapbox* :

```
function addMDA_toA()
{ 

alert("Function has started.");  // verifies the function started by an alert. This works.


var url = 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/';
topleftmapbox.on('load', function () {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        topleftmapbox.getSource('drone').setData(url);
    }, 2000);

    topleftmapbox.addSource('drone', { type: 'geojson', data: url });
    topleftmapbox.addLayer({
        "id": "drone",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "drone",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "rocket-15"
        }
    });
});

}
```

I am still new with JS and Mapbox in general, so I figure the onload() function is not needed, since I am calling the function from an external click. And so I removed it (and the associated brackets) as far as I can tell because I am learning - resulting in the code below which still does nothing. Again, all I am trying to do is get the Mapbox example [that I previously linked to](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/) working on my own map as it is, with my own function so I can call it when I wish. Below was the second try that also did not work. What am I doing wrong? I don't feel I am changing anything.

```
function addMDA_toA(){


alert("Function has started.");




var url = 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/';

    window.setInterval(function() {
        topleftmapbox.getSource('drone').setData(url);
    }, 2000);

    topleftmapbox.addSource('drone', { type: 'geojson', data: url });
    topleftmapbox.addLayer({
        "id": "drone",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "drone",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "rocket-15"
        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code block above was *correct*, in fact. It is a good example of how to load an external geoJSON file. The problem was resolved after I re-typed the functions and the code that executed it. I looked it over and there were no issues.  The real issue was **messy code**, so if anyone sees this I would like to remind you to keep the code clean and readable as it could confuse others but also yourself.